# How to get a value from dictionary which is inside an array?

Tags: ios, parsing

I want to store a message - "hi this is John KL", in some string, how to parse following example.

```
[
    {
        "message": "hi this is John KL"
    }
]
```

Comment: as a begiiner show what you wrote to get the problem solve. By the way here is your code let dictData = yourArrayOfDict[index] as Dictionary.  let valueObject = dictData["message"]. for parsing JSON look into this link http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/12/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-3/  Use JSONSerialization to get the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this answer.

```
NSArray *result = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
        for(NSString *currenObject in result){
            NSLog(@"%@",currenObject);
           NSString *currentValue = [currenObject valueForKey:@"message"];
}

  NSLog(@"%@",currentValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Swift:

```
guard let anArray = input as? [[String:String]],
      let message = anArray.first["message"] else {
  print("unable to fetch data"
}
```

### Objective-C:

```
- (void) readJSON {
    NSError *result;
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"sample" 
      withExtension: @"JSON"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url  
      options: 0 
      error: &result];
    if (result != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", result);
        return;
    }
    NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString*, NSString*> *> *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: &result];
    if (result != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error converting JSON: %@", result);
        return;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"\nJSON data = \n%@", array);
        if (array.count < 1) {
            NSLog(@"Not enough elements in array");
            return;
        }
        NSString *message = array[0][@"message"];
        if (message == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to fetch message");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Message = \"%@\"", message);
        }
    }
}
```

The above Objective-C code does not test to make sure the object read from the JSON file is the correct type. It will crash if it is not an array containing a dictionary with a string key and string value. For a production app you'll want to add code to type-check the data.

Comment: The question is asked specifically with Objective-C tag

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Um, no, it wasn't. I looked, and there were no language-specific tags when I answered it. The OP added that tag after I answered it.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

Assign your json array to a variable type of `[String : String]` or `[String : Any]` dictionary array. `[String : Any]` is most commonly used dictionary but according to your data it suites with `[String : String]`

```
if let array = [
                 {
                     “message” : “hi this is John KL”
                 }
               ] as [Any]
```

Now, get your json/dictionary from array using index value and then get string from json using json key.

```
if let dictionary = array.first as? [String : Any] {
   if let stringMessage = dictionary["message"] as? String {
       print("stringMessage - \(stringMessage)")
   }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSArray * array = [
                     {
                         “message” : “hi this is John KL”
                     }
                   ];


NSDictionary * dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex: 0];

NSString * stringMessage = (NSString *)[dictionary valueForKey: "message"];

NSLog(@"stringMessage - %@",stringMessage);
```

Comment: Well done providing both Swift and Objective-C code. (Voted.) You might want to add a type specifier on your array so you don't have to cast it though. It also could use error-checking.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks, you are welcomed to edit and improve this answer !

Comment: My Objective-C is rusty these days. I have to look up the typed array/dictionary syntax if I want to use it.

Comment: I posted a full Objective-C method complete with JSON decoding and a strongly typed NSArray in my answer.